# UIImagePickerController doesn't record video or take photo on iOS 14

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios14

I have this code

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .camera
picker.cameraDevice = .rear
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
picker.cameraCaptureMode = .video
picker.videoMaximumDuration = 15.0
picker.videoQuality = .typeLow
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.delegate = self
picker.showsCameraControls = true
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code work properly below iOS 14. On iOS 14 show black screen on preview and doesn't record video or taking photo.

I set properly:

- Privacy - Camera Usage Description
- Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

I check this:

```
UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear)
UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
```

Both methods return true.
I don't use modal dialogs for starting UIImagePickerController.

In console I see this messages:

[Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}

[Camera] [CAMCaptureEngine] Received a session runtime error notification : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.}

Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Update:

I found problem. If comment picker.videoQuality = .typeLow it will works on iOS 14.

Why I can't use low quality on iOS14?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64061582/14351818

Comment: I already checked this thread. Those comments didn't help me.