# UIImagepickercontroller - Camera is not working

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

This is my imagepicker class

```
import UIKit

public protocol ImagePickerDelegate: AnyObject {
   func didSelect(image: UIImage?) 
}

open class ImagePicker: NSObject {

    private let pickerController: UIImagePickerController
    private weak var presentationController: UIViewController?
    private weak var delegate: ImagePickerDelegate?

    public init(presentationController: UIViewController, delegate: ImagePickerDelegate) {
       self.pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    
       super.init()
    
       self.presentationController = presentationController
       self.delegate = delegate
    
       self.pickerController.delegate = self
       self.pickerController.allowsEditing = true
       self.pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
  }

  private func action(for type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, title: String) -> UIAlertAction? {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(type) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { [unowned self] _ in
        self.pickerController.sourceType = type
        self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated:
        true)
    }
}

func openCamera() {
    self.pickerController.sourceType = .camera
    self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true)
}

func openPhotoLibrary() {
    self.pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true)
}

public func present(from sourceView: UIView) {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    if let action = self.action(for: .camera, title: Localization.set(key: .take_photo)) {
        alertController.addAction(action)
    }
    
    if let action = self.action(for: .savedPhotosAlbum, title: Localization.set(key: .camera_roll)) {
        alertController.addAction(action)
    }
    
    if let action = self.action(for: .photoLibrary, title: Localization.set(key: .photo_library)) {
        alertController.addAction(action)
    }
    
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Localization.set(key: .cancel), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections
        = [.down, .up]
    }
    
    self.presentationController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
}

private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, didSelect image: UIImage?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
} }

extension ImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: nil)
}

public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        return self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: nil)
    }
    self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: image)
} }

extension ImagePicker: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
 }
```

This is how I used this class

```
 self.imagePicker = ImagePicker(presentationController: self, delegate: self)

 //MARK:- ImagePickerDelegate 
 extension AddEditGroupViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {
     func didSelect(image: UIImage?) {
         if let wnwrappedImage = image , let imageData = wnwrappedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0){
        
            self.changePhotoView.profileImageView.image = wnwrappedImage
            imageParams = ["group_photo" : imageData]
        }
    } 
}
```

It's working fine for photo gallery and saved photo album but When I try to open camera, it's giving me error as follows

`**[Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}**`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) have you added `NSCameraUsageDescription` in Info.plist? 2) Please, check this thread. It seems like this is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061582/xcode-camera-failed-to-read-exposurebiasesbymode-dictionary

Comment: @Vlad I have added permission in info.plist file, I checked all threads but it seems not working for me.
I also put this code  in another controller and it's working fine but in particular controller it is giving me error